# can't drop index because its name is an integer

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have some indexes in a table which name **is a number(1,2,3,4...)**

But when i use the drop command to remove the index i get a **1064 error**

```
DROP INDEX 1 ON table_name;
```

So my guess is that i cant drop an index when its name is a number? or there is something else i dont know here?

How can it work locally and not on the server?

Error output:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 on table_name' at line 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround `1` with backticks, i.e.

```
DROP INDEX `1` ON table_name;
```